# Running a PL/SQL procedure in a Perl script

Tags: database, perl, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a Perl script which takes a file as input and has PL/SQL (for statements and `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`) in it. I need to run make a database connection and run that file in Perl script.The pl/sql has Begin declare end section,with for statements on it which is writing data of 3 columns separated using commas(DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE) I have shown what I have tried below. Is it correct?

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:$db", $username, $passwd ) ||
        die( $DBI::errstr . "\n" );
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
$dbh->{PrintError} = 1;

open FILE, $sql_file or die "Could not open file";

$query = '';
while($line = <FILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    $query .= $line;
}

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

$sth->execute();

while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    foreach (@row) {
        print "$_";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Would be handy to give us an idea of what might be in the file. You mention procedures and then show none. Has the pl/sql got a begin/end block around it etc. How does it produce a result-set - given your perl suggests it might.

Comment: Does it work or does it print an error message? Also, you should always `use strict` and `use warnings`, and you should get used to the three-argument form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), which is more secure than the form you are using..

Answer (score 4):

`$sth->fetch()`, `$sth->fetchrow_*()`, and friends all fetch records from a result set. In Oracle PL/SQL blocks don't normally return result sets. So calling `$sth->fetchrow_array()` after running a PL/SQL block won't return any results.

If your using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to output results you will need to use the [`dbms_output_*` functions provided by DBD::Oracle](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3aOracle#dbms_output_enable-dbms_output_put-dbms_output_get).

```
my $dbms_output_byte_limit = 1000000;
$dbh->func( $dbms_output_byte_limit, 'dbms_output_enable' );

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

my @text = $dbh->func( 'dbms_output_get' );
```

Comment: If i have a for statement and its running DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE continuously for say a 1000000 rows.Then @text will have 1000000 elements ?

Comment: Yes, you would also need to increase the `$dbms_output_byte_limit` to hold that much data. However, at that point you should really look into better ways to return your data than `dbms_output`.