# How to execute a Pl sql file from a perl script

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

Hi folks can you please help me in understanding how to call a pl sql file from perl script

I have a pl sql file like this

```
DECLARE
 x NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
  IF MOD(i,2) = 0 THEN     -- i is even
     INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is even');
  ELSE
     INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is odd');
  END IF;
  x := x + 100;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

The file is named test.sql I want to call this file from a perl script. I know first we have to connect to db and then perform the process but I Don now know how to execute this file from a perl script

Comment: Have you tried the [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) module?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful (it may not be quite the same, but perhaps it can give you a couple of ideas on how to proceed): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612713/running-a-pl-sql-procedure-in-a-perl-script

Comment: Hi tlp with dbi I heard we can process only one statement at a time how to overcome that thanks for your reply

Comment: See [Perl DBI - run SQL Script with multiple statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232950/perl-dbi-run-sql-script-with-multiple-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to

- use the DBI module with the appropriate driver (Oracle or whatever)
- slurp in the script into a variable by using plain perl
- open a DB connection
- prepare the slurped in script
- execute the statement handle
- disconnect from the DB

Here is an example (I am not showing how to slurp in the script):

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle;

my $service="xxx";
my $user = "yyy";
my $pass = "zzz";

my $DBH = DBI->connect
  (
   "dbi:Oracle:$service", 
   "$user", "$pass",
   { 
    RaiseError => 0, 
    PrintError => 0, 
    AutoCommit => 0, 
    ShowErrorStatement  => 0
   }
  ) or die;

my $script = qq(
    declare
        x number := 1;
    begin
        insert into xxx values (x);
        commit;
    end;
);

my $sth = $DBH->prepare($script) or die;
$sth->execute() or die;

$DBH->disconnect();
```

Comment: Hi Martin by slurp in meaning I'm not getting you

Comment: I mean you make a string variable ($script in my example) whose value is the entire script you want to be executed in the DB. Google for it. It is something like open FILE, "<xxx.pl"; @lines = <FILE>;print "@lines\n";
You don't need to print it of course.

Comment: Hi extremely sorry i'm totally new to perl i found out something as you said but can you help me integrate both ?

Comment: You should be able to figure this out yourself.

Comment: @user2647888 - You asked me to look at this, but I see you accepted this answer. Do you still have a question?